# How to get sessionid from an OpenCPU long running function

Tags: r, opencpu

I have a long-running function on OpenCPU which takes around 1 hour or so to complete.

I read that OpenCPU now sends session ids and we can retrieve the session id and ping back later to retrieve the output. But when I run my code, the session id is not present in the response.

Here is the relevant section of my code

```
let uri= "http://IP/ocpu/library/mypackage/R/myfunction/json"

   const formData = {
    
      'param1' : 'value1',
      'param2' : 'value2',
      'file1': fs.createReadStream('files/.....'),
      'file2': fs.createReadStream('files/...'),
      'file3': fs.createReadStream('files/....')
    };

    const response = await request.post({
      uri: url,
      formData: formData,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
      qs: { async: true }
    });

console.log(response);
```

The response I get is

```
{"uri":{"protocol":"http:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"..myIP..","port":80,"hostname":"MYIP","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/ocpu/library/mypackage/R/myfunction/json","path":"/ocpu/library/..../R/...../json","href":"http://MYIP/ocpu/library/mypackage/R/myfunction/json"},"method":"POST","headers":{"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data","host":"MYIP"}}
```

It does not have the session details.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you specify the language used in above code. Didn't you get an error for `'param1' : 'value1,`

Comment: The code is written in Nodejs. Sorry, that was a typo while writing here. Did not get any error. @Waldi

Comment: Session ids are relatively recent  to the OpenGPU api. Could you verify that you are not using an older version?